# Magento 2 - Order Id increment jumps

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

In my sales > Orders what I'm seeing is order is not continuous it jumps after some orders. Attaching screenshot for your reference

[image]

As above you can see that it directly jumps from 000008844 to 000008848. I have gone thought this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935117/magento-order-id-increment-jumps but there they have only mentioned theory. I don't want any ordered to be removed. How do I do that?

Comment: Please check if in database those orders are missing too (wit id 2245, 2246 and so on)

Comment: The missing numbers indicate abandoned carts